# MySQL Group by with CASE

Tags: mysql

I have a responses table which has a dataset like this...

```
id|resp_id|value|is_cleaned
1  1       Yes   0
2  1       No    1
3  2       No    0
```

I would like to get all the responses where is_cleaned = 1, if it doesnt exist i would like to get the uncleaned result. What i have tried so far is, grouping by resp_id and using CASE statement. Not sure what exactly to put in the CASE statement though.

What i have so far is

```
SELECT * FROM cleanedresponse GROUP BY case when is_cleaned = 1 then resp_id else resp_id end
```

I would like the following results

```
resp_id|value|is_cleaned
1       No    1
2       No    0
```

Comment: what is your expected result??

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by getting the `max(is_cleaned)` for each `resp_id` first

```
select  resp_id, max(is_cleaned)
from    cleanedresponse 
group by resp_id
```

and then using it as a filter in the original table

```
select  t1.resp_id, t1.value, t1.is_cleaned
from    cleanedresponse t1
join    (
            select  resp_id, max(is_cleaned) as max_cleaned
            from    cleanedresponse 
            group by resp_id
        ) t2
on      t1.resp_id = t2.resp_id and
        t1.is_cleaned = t2.max_cleaned
```